# How to avoid optional word from the app?

Tags: macos, macros, swift2

[image]

I removed optional from assistance editor by unwrapping but how to get rid of it in the app and get only the number in answer and not the optional word with it?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two optionals(text from textfield, String to Integer typecasting) you can use the multiple if let conditions here

```
if let catText = catAge.text ,let cat = Int(catText) {
   let age = cat * 7
   catAge.text = "your cat is \(age) years old"
}
```

Comment: Almost; you get the value from `catAge.text` and then set `catAge.text` with the description?!?